# Best way to select from a list

Tags: python, list, loops

This is a loop that allows the user to select only an item from the list.

```
types = ['Small', 'Medium','Large']
while True:
    print('Types: '+ types)
    choice = raw_input('Choose a type. ').capitalize()
    if choice in types:
        choice = choice
        break
    else:
        choice = raw_input('Choose a type. ').capitalize()
```

I was wondering if there's an even smaller & cleaner version of this loop. A try except version maybe.
Is this the best way to write it? Alternatives?

Any ideas?

Comment: What Python version? You seem to be mixing 3 and 2 (print() and raw_input))

Comment: Second version. Its just a habit that i use the 3rd version's print().

Comment: Got it, that can be misleading :)

Comment: You should drop the last two lines of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several lines are unnecessary, I'll show them commented:

```
types = ['Small', 'Medium','Large']
while True:
    print('Types: '+ types)
    choice = raw_input('Choose a type. ').capitalize()
    if choice in types:
        #choice = choice  this is superfluos
        break
     #else: no need for else since the loop will execute again and do exactly this
     #    choice = raw_input('Choose a type. ').capitalize()
```

It will end up in something like:

```
types = ['Small', 'Medium','Large']
while True:
    print('Types: '+ types)
    choice = raw_input('Choose a type. ').capitalize()
    if choice in types:
        break
```

Note: If you don't want to repeat `Types` every time just move the `print` out of the loop:

```
types = ['Small', 'Medium','Large']
print('Types: '+ types)
while True:
    ...
```

Also, your code is not being consistent with an specific Python version, either you use `raw_input()` or `print()` with parenthesis but not mixed (unless you do some `__future__` importing).

Answer (score 1):

The same without needless code:

```
types = ['Small', 'Medium','Large']
print('Types: '+ types)
while True:
    choice = raw_input('Choose a type. ').capitalize()
    if choice in types:
        break
```